# Using scrapy I get an empty item

Tags: python, scrapy

I want to crawl some information from a webpage using python and scrapy, but when I try to do it the output of my item is empty...

First of all I've started a new project with scrapy. Then I've written the following in the items.py file:

```
import scrapy

class KakerlakeItem(scrapy.Item):
    info=scrapy.Field()
    pass
```

Next, I've created a new file in the spider's folder with the following code:

```
import scrapy

from kakerlake.items import KakerlakeItem

class Kakerlakespider(scrapy.Spider):
    name='Coco'
    allowed_domains=['http://www.goeuro.es/']
    start_urls=['http://www.goeuro.es/search/NTYzY2U2Njk4YzA1ZDoyNzE2OTU4ODM=']

    def parse(self, response):
        item=KakerlakeItem()
        item['info']=response.xpath('//span[@class= "inline-b height-100"]/text()').extract()
        #yield item
        return item
```

I expect, by writing `scrapy crawl Coco -o data.json` in the console, that I will get what I want, but instead of this I obtain the json file with `{'info': []}`. That is, an empty item.

I've tried a lot of things and I don't know why it doesn't work correctly...

Comment: Are you sure the XPath is correct? I opened the url from your code but couldn't find the element there... Looking at the web, it is highly probable that the source changed since you looked.

Comment: I wanted to get the time that the airplane (for example) needs. I thought the xpath was correct...
Thank you!

Comment: I tried a lot of things using scrapy to crawl some data from the following website: http://www.skyscanner.es

But I still get an empty item using this new website and I don't know why... It's may be because Javascript or may be because the website detect that a program is trying to get data and then it doesn't allow the program... 

I try also phantomjs and selenium but I don't get what I want... I'm willing  a program that crawls every day  this webpage and take some particular data.
If some of you could give me some advice it would we great!

Answer (score 0):

Your xpath is invalid for the page, as there isn't a single class with "inline-b" or "height-100".  This page is heavily modified via Javascript, so what you see in a browser will not be representative of what Scrapy receives.

xpath results:

```
>>> response.xpath('//span[contains(@class, "inline-b")]')
[]
>>> response.xpath('//span[contains(@class, "height-100")]')
[]
```

Comment: Oh, I see... Then, if I want to get the time that it takes to the airplane (for example), what should I write?
Thank you!!

Comment: From what I see and guess (I don't know the foreign language), there is a "departure-datetime" and "arrival-datetime" for each flight.  Maybe you can get both time points and calculate the difference (the flight time) later.

Comment: Thank you, but I still get an empty item doing what you have recommended me. I don't know how to get some pieces of information of that particular website... I'm able to crawl information of other websites, but not of that one...

Answer (score -1):

Remove the pass in KakerlakeItem(scrapy.Item) ?

Comment: Although it serves no purpose, `pass` does nothing here.  See the documentation for `pass` [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#pass-statements).